# php error Warning - implode() [<a href='function.implode'>function.implode</a>]: Invalid arguments passed

Tags: php, arrays

> /var/www/html/development/cross/doli/www/app/service/class.order_management.php(2955) : Warning - implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed

my following code looks like this -

```
$campaign_id = (empty($param_array['CampaignID']))?$split['campaign_sku']:$param_array['CampaignID'];
        $campaign_array = $this->get_campaign($job_type, $campaign_id, $split['skus'], $split['client_skus']);
        $job_type_array[] = $job_type;
        $this->client_obj_guid = $split['client_obj_guid'];
        $avail_param = array('client' => $this->client_obj_guid,
            'campaign' => $campaign_array[0],
            'digiSku' => $split['primary'],
            'skus' => implode(',', $split['secondary']),**The error is happening here, so I figure I would need to check $split to see if it is a array. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.**
            'zip' => $customer_zip,
            'pos' => $pos_guid,
            'pos_sku' => $param_array['StoreID'],
            'inst' => $this->default_inst_obj_guid,
            'offer_count'=>(isset($param_array['NumberOfOfferings']))?$param_array['NumberOfOfferings']:'24',
            'job_type'=>$routing_job_type,
            'job_skus' => implode(',', $split['skus']),
            'total_capacity_units'=>$sku_array[$job_type]['capacity_units']);
```

Comment: You must check if `$split['secondary']` is an array then you can invoke implode function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score 1):

The function `implode` is expecting an array, but the parameter passed to it may be not an array. So, you have to check if `$split['secondary']` is an array or not. You can check this as below:

`'skus' => is_array($split['secondary']) ? implode(',', $split['secondary']) : ''`

This code will put empty string `''` into `skus` if `$split['secondary']` is not an array.